# How to block external resources to load on a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, ios8, wkwebview

I have an app that loads a webpage, but prevents the downloads of images, fonts, javascripts, etc. For this I implemented an `NSURLProtocol` subclass which works very well with UIWebView.

However I'm migrating to `WKWebview`, and realise that my crafted `NSURLProtocol` class no longer works to filter out these resources.

Have anyone an insight as to how to achive the filtering/blocking?

In case you're wondering how am I doing the migration, I started with this post: http://floatlearning.com/2014/12/uiwebview-wkwebview-and-tying-them-together-using-swift/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since iOS 11 you can use `WKContentRuleList`

First, create a Content Rule or a list. Each rule is comprised of a trigger and an action. See
[Apple's Documentation on Content Rule creation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Extensions/Conceptual/ContentBlockingRules/CreatingRules/CreatingRules.html)

This is a creation example, blocks all image and Style Sheet content, but allows those ended on *jpeg* by way of ignoring the previous rules:

```
     let blockRules = """
         [{
             "trigger": {
                 "url-filter": ".*",
                 "resource-type": ["image"]
             },
             "action": {
                 "type": "block"
             }
         },
         {
             "trigger": {
                 "url-filter": ".*",
                 "resource-type": ["style-sheet"]
             },
             "action": {
                 "type": "block"
             }
         },
         {
             "trigger": {
                 "url-filter": ".*.jpeg"
             },
             "action": {
                 "type": "ignore-previous-rules"
             }
         }]
      """
```

Having your list of rules, you can add them to the ContentRuleListStore

```
    import WebKit
    @IBOutlet weak var wkWebView: WKWebView!

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://yourSite.com/")!)

    WKContentRuleListStore.default().compileContentRuleList(
        forIdentifier: "ContentBlockingRules",
        encodedContentRuleList: blockRules) { (contentRuleList, error) in

            if let error = error {
                return
            }

            let configuration = self.webView.configuration
            configuration.userContentController.add(contentRuleList!)

            self.wkWwebView.load(self.request)
    }
```

If later you want to remove all your rules, call:

```
    self.wkWebView.configuration.userContentController.removeAllContentRuleLists()
    self.wkWebView.load(self.request)
```

Here is the [2017 WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/220/)

Best of lucks!

I've created a sample project [on Github WKContentRuleExample](https://github.com/dequin-cl/WKContentRuleExample)

Comment: Have you any suggestion for an implementation working for iOS < 11 ?

Comment: Not at this time, sorry. Couldn't find any API before iOS 11

Comment: how to block external resources to load on a WKWebView with iOS 10 ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no blocking resources before iOS 11

Answer (score 5):

In case anybody else is interested in an **offline-only `WKWebView`**: The following approach is a modification of @dequin's answer. It uses content blocking rules to block all requests to remote resources (URLs that don't start with `file://`):

```swift
import Cocoa
import WebKit

// Block all URLs except those starting with "file://"
let blockRules = """
[
    {
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": ".*"
        },
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        }
    },
    {
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": "file://.*"
        },
        "action": {
            "type": "ignore-previous-rules"
        }
    }
]
"""
```

```swift
/// `WKWebView` which only allows the loading of local resources
class OfflineWebView: WKWebView {
    override init(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration) {
        WKContentRuleListStore.default().compileContentRuleList(
            forIdentifier: "ContentBlockingRules",
            encodedContentRuleList: blockRules
        ) { contentRuleList, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle error
            } else if let contentRuleList = contentRuleList {
                configuration.userContentController.add(contentRuleList)
            } else {
                // Handle error
            }
        }

        super.init(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 9.0 there is no way to intercept network requests for the `WKWebView`. You can do this with JavaScript in a limited way.

Please file a WebKit bug or an Apple bug to request this functionality. Many of us are in need of these hooks.

Comment: I would say it is NOT a WebKit bug. Android has had functions to do this for quite some time. Blocking Image loading (and many other things) has been there from the start. Apple simply hasn't exposed those features.

Comment: Filing a bug is the best way to let apple know that this is functionality that we would access to.

Comment: @StefanArentz any hints on how implement it for iOS < 11 ?

Comment: @NicholasAllio just a thought: probably you can inject Content Security Policy meta tag into the webpage before it will start loading resources. With help of WKUserScripts maybe