# Disable loading images in WKWebView ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I am creating an app, in which [supremenewyork.com](https://supremenewyork.com) website is loaded in `WKWebView`. But when the website is loaded I do not want to load images in it. How can I do this in Objective-C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to block external resources to load on a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119975/how-to-block-external-resources-to-load-on-a-wkwebview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have following which prevent to load images of website in WKWebView. I have used content blocker rules which are documented official web site of Apple. Check here. [Creating a Content Blocker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/creating_a_content_blocker).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

//    id blockRules = @" [{ \"trigger\": { \"url-filter\": \".*\", \"resource-type\": [\"image\"] }, \"action\": { \"type\": \"block\" } }, { \"trigger\": { \"url-filter\": \".*\", \"resource-type\": [\"style-sheet\"]          }, \"action\": { \"type\": \"block\" } }, { \"trigger\": { \"url-filter\": \".*.jpeg\" }, \"action\": {              \"type\": \"ignore-previous-rules\" } }] ";

    id blockRules = @" [{ \"trigger\": { \"url-filter\": \".*\", \"resource-type\": [\"image\"] }, \"action\": { \"type\": \"block\" } }] ";

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.supremenewyork.com/"]];

    [[WKContentRuleListStore defaultStore] compileContentRuleListForIdentifier: @"ContentBlockingRules" encodedContentRuleList:blockRules completionHandler:^(WKContentRuleList *contentRuleList, NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error = %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else {
            WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = self.webView.configuration;
            [[configuration userContentController] addContentRuleList:contentRuleList];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.webView loadRequest:request];
            });
        }
    }];
}
```

**Output:**
**1.**
[image: Disable Image Load 1]

**Output:**
**2.**
[image: Disable Image Load 2]

Comment: thanks for solution. Do you also know how to link gmail login with supremenewyork.com to reduce chances of  showing recaptcha.

Comment: You should add `Google Sign In` sdk in your application.

Comment: yes I have implemented google signin in the application but how to put it in website. how website will know user has signed in with Gmail

Comment: Can you send me code example for this?  I would be very thankful you.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142562/loading-a-webpage-through-uiwebview-with-post-parameters/1143020

Comment: Can you please provide solution of this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990796/how-to-enable-and-get-cookies-from-wkwebview

I am asking you because seems like you have already worked on another supremenewyork.com bot app.

Answer (score 2):

This is Swift version based on Mayur Karmur's answer:

```
let blockRules = "[{ \"trigger\": { \"url-filter\": \".*\", \"resource-type\": [\"image\"] }, \"action\": { \"type\": \"block\" } }]";

WKContentRuleListStore.default().compileContentRuleList(forIdentifier: "ContentBlockingRules", encodedContentRuleList: blockRules) {
  contentRuleList, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error =", error.localizedDescription);
    }else if let contentRuleList = contentRuleList{
        let configuration = self.webView.configuration;
        configuration.userContentController.add(contentRuleList);
    }
}
```