# How to enable and get cookies from WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, wkwebview

I want to enable the cookies of `WKWebView` so that if user log in gmail or solve recaptcha in `WKWebView`, it should not be asked to log in gmail or solve recaptcha again.

I also want to get those cookies so that I can pass those cookies to other instance of `WKWebView` on other screen.

I am using following code to get cookies but it is returning 0 count of cookies.

```
[dataStore.httpCookieStore getAllCookies:^(NSArray *cookies) {
        [self->settings setCookies:cookies];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"browserShouldReload" object:nil];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
```

please let me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To manager the cookies of a application context uses

HTTPCookieStorage shared instance

To get all the cookies:

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies
```

it will bring all the cookies in a HTTPCookie array if exists`[HTTPCookie]?`

---

also you can get the cookies for a specific url

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: "https://www.gmail.com")
```

---

if you want you can remove all cookies too, from a date that you want

```
 HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)
```

And a lot of others things with  `HTTPCookieStorage.shared` object

---

see [HTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookiestorage) on the Apple Developer Documentation for more